# removeClass() is not getting applied in IE6.0

Tags: jquery

I am working with jQuery and when I call the `removeClass()` function is not working in IE6.0, what could be the reason? The `.removeClass()` function is working as expected in IE8.0 and Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .message-header{
            margin-left:10px;
            padding-left:15px; 
            border:1px solid #fff; 
            border:0px solid #ddd;  
        }  

        .message-header.closed{  
            margin-left:10px;  
            padding-left:15px; 
            border:1px solid #fff;    
            border:0px solid #ddd;   
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    this is my jsp.
    <script>
        $(document.ready(function()){
            var $content = $('.message-header', node);{

            if (action == 'hide') {
                $content.addClass('closed');
                $content.hide();
            }
            else if (action == 'view') {
                $content.removeClass('closed');
                $content.show();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray opening brace. And your `document.ready` syntax is wrong.

Here is a corrected version.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $content = $('.message-header', node); // { <-- stray

    if (action == 'hide') {
        $content.addClass('closed').hide();
    }
    else if (action == 'view') {
        $content.removeClass('closed').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 from me. Hi @Raj if your not already, I'd suggest using an IDE with JavaScript syntax highlighting that way it'll help you spot missing braces etc.

Comment: thanks Alex Key for your suggestion. i will definitely use that.